# No module named 'twilio.rest.api.v2010.account

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

I tried this code

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = ...
auth_token = ...
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
                              from_= "+19785408307",
                              body='Hi there',
                              to="+905050782635"
                          )

print(message.sid)
```

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\python100\WEATHER_API\msg.py", line 12, in <module>
    message = client.messages.create(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 680, in messages
    return self.api.account.messages
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 211, in api
    from twilio.rest.api import Api
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010 import V2010
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account import AccountContext
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip import SipList
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain import DomainList
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types import AuthTypesList
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_registrations_mapping import AuthTypeRegistrationsList
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\auth_registrations_mapping\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_registrations_mapping.auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping import AuthRegistrationsCredentialListMappingList
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_registrations_mapping.auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping'
```

I tried to reinstall twilio again with pip but I have got the same error

iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: What version of the Twilio Python library do you have installed in your application? Also, you seem to have included your account's auth token in the example, I recommend you follow [this article to change your auth token](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them) as others can steal this one and abuse your account with it.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the `twilio` package.
then reinstalled with this command and it works somehow.

```
pip3 install twilio>=6.0.0
```